# Deny delete permission when saving file from IE

Tags: permissions

I am trying to setup an networkshare in which users can add/write files but are not able to delete them. So I tried this with special permissions:
Domain\Usergroup - Special Permissions **Allow** Special Permission except 2 options: Delete subfolders and files and Delete
Domain\Usergroup - Special Permissions **Deny** Delete subfolders and files and Delete

This works right as long as I work from Word/Excel etc. The problem is that when I try to save a file from Internet Explorer an error occurs:

You are not able to change files in this networklocation. Please contact your system manager....

If I check the destination folder I can see the file but it's only 0 kb...

Comment: IE 9 and + got builtin a download manager that create amd erase .partial file, check with process monitor if its not that feature that stop you.

Answer (score 1):

Can you download the file to your C-drive and then manually copy the file to the network share? 
When you download something in Internet Explorer, it is firstly saved to a temp location on your local drive, and will then be copied to the network location

Comment: Yes if I download it to my harddrive I can than afterwards copy it to the networkshare. Because it is a webapplication I need to be able to directly save tot the share